# How to show that the language made up of strings with nlogn 0s is not regular with the pumping lemma?

Tags: regular-languages, pumping-lemma

How to show that the following language is not regular with the pumping lemma?

$$L=\left\{0^{n\lceil\log_2 n\rceil} \,\middle|\, n\in \mathbb{N}-\{0\}\right\}.$$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prove that a language is not regular?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1031/how-to-prove-that-a-language-is-not-regular)

Comment: This seems like homework, what did you try, and where are you stuck?

Comment: Did you consider accepting my answer? (This comment will be removed.)

Answer (score 3):

(**Dense-length lemma for regular languages**) Let $R$ be an regular language that has infinitely many words. Then there exists a number $d$ such that for any word in $R$, there is another word such that the difference of the lengths of both words is less than $d$.

The above lemma says, basically, the lengths of words in a regular language cannot be too sparse anywhere. It can be proved easily using the pumping lemma for regular languages.

Let us take a look at $L$. The lengths of its word are $\{n\lceil\log_2 n\rceil \,\mid n\in \Bbb{N}-\{0\}\}$. When $n$ goes larger and larger, the lengths become sparser and sparser because of the factor $\lceil\log_2n\rceil$. In fact, if $n>2^d$, $m>2^d$ and $n\not=m$, then $\left|n\lceil\log_2n\rceil-m\lceil\log_2m\rceil\right| > d$. So $L$ cannot be regular because of the above lemma.

---

Exercise 1. Prove the dense-length lemma for regular languages.

Exercise 2. Prove the dense-length lemma also holds for context-free languages that have infinitely many words.

Exercise 3. Does the dense-length lemma hold for context-sensitive languages?

Comment: Hint for exercise 1, the pumping lemma for regular languages.